# how to add key and value in dictionary python?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I am trying to add some value and key in python dictionary using following script

```
print('phone book contacts')
contacts = input('how many contacts to add: ')
i = 0
for i in range(int(contacts)):
  phone_book = {}
  a = input('name: ')
  b = input('number: ')
  phone_book[a] = b
print(phone_book)
```

when i input 2 key & value like these:

```
adam : 08123
daniel : 0877
```

I expect the output will be like these:

```
{'adam':'08123', 'daniel':'0877'}
```

instead I get the following output:

```
{'daniel': '1234'}
```

any ideas how to show dictionary key & value similar with my expected output?

Comment: `phone_book = {}` creates a new dictionary each iteration. Move that to before the loop.

Comment: I see I never expected this solution. thank u for ur advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
class my_dictionary(dict):  
  
    # __init__ function  
    def __init__(self):  
        self = dict()  
          
    # Function to add key:value  
    def add(self, key, value):  
        self[key] = value  
  
# Main Function  
dict_obj = my_dictionary()  
  
# Taking input key = 1, value = test
dict_obj.key = input("Enter the key: ") 
dict_obj.value = input("Enter the value: ") 
  
dict_obj.add(dict_obj.key, dict_obj.value)  
dict_obj.add(2, 'test2')  
  
print(dict_obj)
```

Comment: I have tried it, but it doesn't allow me to input key & value more than once. I need to be able to input multiple key & value in dictionary

Comment: @Ahmad_20 you can handle that logic in for loop based on your entry length

Comment: I don't see a reason to subclass `dict` here. Why not use a dictionary directly?

Answer (score 0):

Use `update()` method of dictionary class in python.
So if applied to your code

It would be

```py
print('phone book contacts')
contacts = input('how many contacts to add: ')
i = 0
phone_book = {}
for i in range(int(contacts)):
  a = input('name: ')
  b = int(input('number: '))
  phone_book.update({a : b})
print(phone_book)
```

Since number is integer you have to use curly braces.

And yes move `phone_book = {}` above the loop because it will be set to empty every time it loops.